# How to use a loop to delete all rows with negative values in R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I am new to loops. I have an unwieldy data frame that I want to cut down so that only observations (rows) without negative numbers remain. Here is where I'm stuck. This creates a null value every time instead of a trimmed down data frame.

```
    mydata=for (i in names(df)) {
      subset(df, df[[ paste(i)]]>=0) 
    }
```

Comment: do you need a loop to do that????

Comment: Maybe `mydata <- df[!rowSums(df < 0),]`

Comment: @RHertel - just beat me... :(

Comment: @Symbolix No problem. This happens to all of us on a regular basis (maybe not to akrun though:-D ).

Comment: @RHertel - surprised not to see him on this one; he must be taking a nap :)

Comment: nah, you never see him coming. He is like a ninja :)

Comment: Thank you! @RHertel It worked very well, and its so simple! Genious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a purely vectorised solution:

```
DF[!rowSums(DF < 0), ]
#  ID Items Sequence
#1  1     D        1
#2  1     A        2
#5  2     B        2
```

---

Data

```
DF=structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, -1, 2), Items = c("D", "A", "A", 
"A", "B"), Sequence = c(1, 2, -2, 1, 2)), .Names = c("ID", "Items", 
"Sequence"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

**Explanation**

The comparison `DF < 0` gives `TRUE/FALSE` for every value in the data.frame

```
DF < 0
#         ID Items Sequence
# [1,] FALSE FALSE    FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE    FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE     TRUE
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE    FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE    FALSE
```

`rowSums()` then gives us the sum of each row (as `TRUE == 1, FALSE == 0`)

```
rowSums(DF<0)
# [1] 0 0 1 1 0
```

So we can use this vector to subset our data.frame. But, because we want it where the values are all positive (i.e. rowSums == 0), we negate the filter

```
DF[!rowSums(DF < 0), ]
```

Comment: @RHertel - I saw your comment after I posted, I swear !

Answer (score 3):

You don't need loops for this :)

```
DF=structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, -1, 2), Items = c("D", "A", "A", 
"A", "B"), Sequence = c(1, 2, -2, 1, 2)), .Names = c("ID", "Items", 
"Sequence"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

 DF
#  ID Items Sequence
#1  1     D        1
#2  1     A        2
#3  1     A       -2
#4 -1     A        1
#5  2     B        2


new_DF = DF[apply(DF<0,1,function(x) !any(x)),]

new_DF
#  ID Items Sequence
#1  1     D        1
#2  1     A        2
#5  2     B        2
```

Comment: Thanks, I bundled the `apply` with others `lapply`,`mapply` etc